# SQL refer Primary Key in same Table and Query

Tags: sql

I am maintaining a table of Items (**Id** is **Primary Key**). Some Items have **Parent Item** ( Which is also an Item, the colum **Parent** holds the Id of the parent Item, which is also in the same table. Some Items does not have parent so the value is set to null.

Is there any method or proper design pattern to maintain such an information. (like: The foreign key is also from the same table)

If an Id of an Item is given, What is the recommended way to write a `query` which loop until the parent of item is null.

> eg: Given value is **5**, the query should return **2**.
>
> Parent of **5** is **4**, parent of **4** is **3**, parent of **3** is **2** and **2**'s parent is **null**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          Id         |       Parent     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           1         |          4       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           2         |       null       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           3         |          2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           4         |          3       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           5         |          4       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           6         |       null       |
```

> I am working on a PostgreSQL database, but I beleive the solution is
>   generic and may support SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite or Oracle

Comment: you can check Adjacency Lists: https://blog.duncanworthy.me/sql/hierarchical-data-pt1-adjacency-list/

Comment: You may want to see Bill Karwin's slides on how to work with hierarchical data in a database: https://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query hierarchic tables with recursive queries:

```
with cte(id, parent) as
(
    select id, parent from mytable where id = :id -- <== the starting ID here
    union all
    select m.id, m.parent from cte join mytable m on m.id = cte.parent
)
select id from cte where parent is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql 8.0.26 ,  you can query like this:

ps. the table Name is Employees

```
  select     id,
             parent
  from       Employees
  where      parent = :id
  union all
  select     p.id,
             p.parent
  from       Employees p
  inner join cte
          on p.parent = cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```